# Select a file to upload on one page and upload file on another page

Tags: html

I have a multi-step wizard.
I would like to let user to **select** a file on one page (step #2, for example of the 6-step process), but I want files to be actually uploaded on the last page (confirmation page, step #6).

Is it possible to prompt and capture local file system path on one page, and then upload that file later.

Is single-page-like wizard my only option to accommodate for this workflow?

Comment: No, there is not a way to store a local path and retrieve the specified file later, or to pass uploaded file data from page to page (like you can with other POST data). You will need to handle the upload at the time that it happens.

Comment: However, if you use Javascript to show each step as though it were a separate page, simply showing and hiding the required elements as the user steps through the form, you may be able to accomplish the effect that you desire.

Comment: @George Cummins: Was suspecting that. Make "no, it is impossible due to security considerations" as an answer, so I can select it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to store a local path and retrieve the specified file later, or to pass uploaded file data from page to page (like you can with other POST data). For security reasons, remote sites cannot access files on the client's machine via the browser without direct user input.

You will need to handle the upload at the time that it happens. Alternately, use Javascript/AJAX to hide the fact that you are not performing new page loads while the user progresses through the steps.